# Valid json check in C language

Tags: c, json, json-c

I have searched a lot in Google. I want to programmatically check if the string below is valid JSON in C. How can I do that? (I am currently using the `json-c` library.)

```
        char * string = "{
                      number1 : 100,
                    number2 : 10,
                    files : [ c , c++, java,PHP,java,PHP ],
                    random: [123567876523333,908,988]
                    }";
```

The library has no function to check if the string is valid JSON.

Comment: Looks ok. Why not just try it?

Comment: I want to programmatically check whether the string is valid json or not..

Comment: Well if it's not valid JSON I would expect the parsing to fail and return some sort of error.

Comment: Just pick a library of your choice and get it to decode it. It will say yes/no if valid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function `json_tokener_parse(const char *str)`, it returns `NULL` if parsing fails.

See [here](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__tokener_8h.html#abf031fdf1e5caab71e2225a99588c6bb) for details.

Comment: Is there any way to check it without parsing it though? 
I would like to avoid performance and memory penalty of parsing the JSON.