# json_tokener_parse ， Segmentation fault

Tags: c, json-c

```
void TestSegFunction(void)
{
     int i = 0;
     char *str = "\"{\"loop_number\":1}\""; // line 410
     char *str = "{\"loop_number\":1}"; // line 411
     json_object *pstObj = NULL;
     json_object *sonPstObj = NULL;
     pstObj = json_tokener_parse(str);    // line 414
     if (NULL == pstObj)
     {
         printf("%s : json_tokener_parse failed.\n", __FUNCTION__);
     }
     else
     {
         json_object_object_foreach(pstObj, key1, val1) 
         {
             if (0 == strcmp(key1, LOOP_NUMBER))
             {
                 i = json_object_get_int(val1);
                 printf("i = %d\n", i);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

As shown in lines 410 and 411, if 410 lines of code are used, there will be a segment error in 414 lines of function calls. If 411 lines of code are used, there will be no error in 414 lines, because this function is called by others, and they may enter an error string. I don't want to see the segment error to stop the program. Is there any way to avoid this kind of paragraph error?

Comment: Is your question not about the invalid JSON object represented by the first string, but rather how to validate it first so you don't get the crash?

Comment: And while it often is unlikely, have you considered that there is a bug in the JSON library you use? Have you thought to create a proper [mcve] (which can be easily copy-pasted in full to replicate the crash) and then report it as a bug to the library maintainers? Which version of the library are you using? Are there later versions available where this might be fixed (if it's a bug in the library)?

Comment: yes, I think i can know in advance that it is an invalid JSON string, so I can avoid this crash. The library is from https://github.com/json-c/json-c.

Comment: @yanzhang.guo Any idea how to go about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890286/modifying-c-json-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I'm trying to iterate over something that isn't of type `json_type_object`.
I need to add a check like

```
if (json_object_get_type(pstObj) != json_type_object) {
   ...handle error...
}
```

before the `json_object_object_foreach`.

This answer comes from https://github.com/json-c/json-c/issues/623.

Comment: Sorry, I quoted the author's answer directly from GitHub.

Comment: Then you should quote it accordingly if you copy someone else's text. And some proper formatting would improve the answer as well.

Comment: Hello, I still do not have the right to ask questions, I have deleted the unclear questions, and I have got the answers I want for other questions. I have checked my question many times, but I still don't know what kind of modification I should make? Can you tell me, thank you!

Comment: Also, why are you posting your answer as community wiki?

Comment: @ 10 Rep Sorry, is there a problem

Comment: I give up. I have no way to solve the problem that I'm forbidden to ask. It's impossible for me to reproduce the original code. The previous code bug has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I makes sense that code line 410 does not work, while 411 does.

```
char *str = "\"{\"loop_number\":1}\"";
```

This is not valid JSON, since a JSON can not start with `"`, what this code line is in fact doing. It gives you the string `"{"loop_number": 1}}"`. Just use c's print function to verify. But a JSON can start with a `{`.

```
char *str = "{\"loop_number\":1}";
```

which gives you the string `{"loop_number": 1}` (See, no " around the `{ }`).

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

As the code breaks on line 414, you may use [`json_tokener_parse_ex`](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__tokener_8h.html#abf031fdf1e5caab71e2225a99588c6bb) directly. In fact, [`json_tokener_parse`](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/blob/55d053118e68834564e238217f6511ad98e19b8d/json_tokener.c#L173) seems to simply wrap `json_tokener_parse_ex`. If you therefore directly use it as described in the [documentation](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__tokener_8h.html#abf031fdf1e5caab71e2225a99588c6bb) and as in [here](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/blob/55d053118e68834564e238217f6511ad98e19b8d/json_tokener.c#L173) you maybe solve this issue. It is however weired, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773273/valid-json-check-in-c-language) advises to solve your problem the way you did it. Maybe it is outdated?

Comment: yes, i know it is an invalid JSON string, i just want to avoid this invalid JSON string.

Comment: What do you mean with avoid? Is it a user input? Or returned form an API? I'm asking because I thought you have full control over what will be in the input to your program based on the example. Of course, this might be my missinterpretation of the code.

Comment: The above code is just a test. I intend to encapsulate it as a function for others, but others may not input a correct JSON string. If so, my program will crash.

Comment: I see. But if it accepts input (from whatever source), you have no choice but live with it. You already checked if the input is a valid json in [code lines 414-418](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773273/valid-json-check-in-c-language). I don't see what else you can do? If it is invalid, it is invalid. You may implement strategies for fixing the most commong problems, but thats about it. Maybe you can add an explanation into  `json_tokener_parse failed` in the print statement to something along the lines `json_tokener_parse failed. This might indicate an invalid JSON.`.

Comment: When the program runs to line 414, it will crash and no longer execute.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you please add this information explicetly to your question? I would suggest as the first sentence before the code listening.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the meaning of 'before the code listening', what should I do?

Comment: Before your code in the question. That way, everyone knows exactly what is going on. :)

Comment: Maybe as Hitokiri said, this is a bug of library function.

Comment: Of course. I assumed that you have tried different version of the library? As we are talking about it, can you please not only add where it breaks but also the library version you are using (and the library versions you have tried)? Thank you.

Comment: The latest version I downloaded from GitHub, I asked the author, but I haven't replied yet.